# There was a problem while parsing the package on programatically installing apk Android

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-fileprovider

I am trying to install apk file programatically in the device, But fails to install as it says **Staging app...** **There was a problem while parsing the package**. Shown below is the message displayed

[image]

Below is the code which is tried in a physical device.

```
private static final String APP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/";

    private void install() {
        File file = new File(APP_DIR + "app.apk");

        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String type = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Uri downloadedApk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(downloadedApk, type);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }

            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ّFile not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

created the `path.xml` file in the `res/xml` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="Download" path="Download/"/>
<!--    <external-path name="external" path="." />-->
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Provided permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

<application...
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path" />
        </provider>
</application>
```

Also tried saving and installing apk from public directories also, which did not help

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Also tried updating the versions of the app before generating signed apk.
Please provide solution to programatically install apk.

Comment: Allow from unknown source is checked in settings?

Comment: or add write external storage permission